# iPhone 12 Pro is not showing 3D model instantly

Tags: iphone, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arkit, arcore

I have developed an AR mobile application with object detection using TensorFlow. The app is running perfectly on iPhone 12 Mini and other iPhones. But when I test it on iPhone 12 Pro and iPad 12 Pro the app is not showing 3D model when the phone camera is far from the detected object. When ever the app detects the trained object it is suppose to show the 3d model and place near to that object but in iPhone 12 pro versions it is only showing 3D object when camera is near to detected object.

I think may be LiDAR is creating problem? If yes, then how to stop the LiDAR using C# code as I have developed the project in Unity using ARFoundation and TensorFlow. I am using ARFoundation 1.0.

Answer (score 1):

ARFoundation 1.0 was released in 2018, so it doesn't support `Meshing` (generation of triangle meshes that correspond to the physical space). So, there may be possible time-lag-problems, because device equipped with a LiDAR scanner must understand that there's no support for `Scene Reconstruction` in a current config, and it must toggled for a common `Plane Detection` approach instead.

**A solution is simple – use the latest version of ARFoundation 4.1.5**.